# What is the correct pronunciation of Eorl the Young's name?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In my mind I had always pronounced Eorl like a cognate of earl, but upon reflection I think that can't be right.

Many of the Rohan royalty have the letters E and O successively in their names, pronounced Ee-oh. Eorl's father was Léod. We meet Théoden, Éomer, Éowyn, and hear of Théodred. All are Ee-oh, but all with an acute accent over the "E." Eorl has no special marking over the first letter of his name, but it can't be because of its position in the word. See, for example, Éowyn and Éomer, both of whom do have initial diacriticals.

Is the correct pronunciation Ee-oh-rl?

Have I been hearing in my mind's ear the pronunciation of Eorl incorrectly all this time?

Comment: I don't pronounce it out loud, usually, but in my mind it is two syllables, long e followed by orl. But then, I'm very casual about such things if not speaking aloud and formally.

Comment: @Lesser son  You are wrong about all members of Rohan royalty having "eo" in their names.  The appendix to ROTK about the House of Eorl gives the names of  of the kings of Rohan, and many don't have "eo" in their names, like, for example, Helm Hammerhand and his sons Haleth  and Hama.

Comment: What I want to know is, did Tolkien ever meet A. A. Milne?

Comment: @Spencer - You'd be best to ask that as a question.

Comment: @ibid I would have, if I really wanted to.  I was thinking about the pronunciation of "Eeyore". ;)

Comment: @ibid but seriously, IIRC one of the Letters was to or from Milne.

Comment: @Spencer - There are no known letters between Tolkien and Milne, but Tolkien does talk about him in one of his essays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an Old English diphthong that did not survive in Modern English.

*Eorl* is an Old English word, the origin of our word *earl*. Tolkien represented nearly all instances of Rohirric as Old English.

One feature of [Old English phonetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_phonology#dipthongs) are a few [dipthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) sounds: aea, iu, and eo.

"Eo" is pronounced [eƏ] sort of like a very fast "aeyo". Long "a" glides into long "o".

Long vowels in Old English, unlike Modern English, are just lengthened versions of short vowels. They're usually transcribed with a macron,  but an accent is often used, and I think this is how Tolkien came up with "Éo".

(Wait a minute! "Most Old English diphthongs consist of a front vowel followed by a back offglide".  Now that I think of it, the Mid-Atlantic accent that I speak has this sound as its most distinctive, replacing most long "o" sounds! Geo reoll up the héose, Hon.)

Comment: I hear Eowyn's name pronounced, more-or-less, A'-O-win and Eomer's A'-O-mer.  (Not proper phonetic symbols, but you get the idea, I hope. Apostrophe indicates stressed syllable.)  If so, Eorl is pretty parallel: either A'-or-al, or is it A'-O-ral?

Comment: @MarkOlson Who did you hear pronounce it? Eo (AO) is one syllable. The A slurs into the O.

Comment: Audiobooks, the films, and, of course, the echoes in my own head. I don't think Tolkien ever pronounced it in the few recordings I've heard of his voice.

Comment: @MarkOlson As I said, the dipthong didn't survive into modern English (my silly aside notwithstanding).  So our voices aren't trained to say it and our ears aren't trained to hear it. Except for Old English scholars like Tolkien.

Comment: This is cognate with modern English [_earl_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earl#Etymology), and also with modern Icelandic [_jarl_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jarl#Icelandic) and Norwegian [_jarl_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jarl#Norwegian_Nynorsk), both pronounced with the "J" sounding like a modern English consonantal "Y". Considering how these other languages pronounce the word, I find it reasonable to suggest that the "EO" in "EORL" would have been pronounced as a glide diphthong a bit like "YO" or "Y∃", not as the distinct "A" + "O" vowels we hear in _Éowyn_ or _Théoden_.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Of course, Old English phonology is reconstructed,  but if you play the clips [here](https://oldenglish.info/advpronunciationguide.html) you'll see that scholars disagree with you.

Comment: @Spencer, FWIW, and speaking subjectively :), those recordings sound to me like "EO" is pretty much a glide diphthong (albeit with an arguably delayed onset of the glide portion), while "ÉO" is clearly two separate vowel sounds. I may have expressed it badly, but that's what I was trying to convey.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Why do you think éo is two separate vowel sounds? Refer to my last comment to MarkOlson.

Comment: @Spencer -- um, because that's how the speaker pronounces it at the site you linked?

Comment: @MarkOlson see ibid's answer for Tolkien saying Eorl.

Answer (score 12):

### There is an audio recording of Tolkien himself saying "Eorl"

One of the longer audio recordings that we have of Tolkien is of him reading a large section from *The Lord of the Rings*, Book V Chapter 5 "The Ride of the Rohirrim".

This recording includes Tolkien saying the word Eorl.

> ‘Now is the hour come, Riders of the Mark, sons of **Eorl**! Foes and fire are before you, and your homes far behind.

It can be clearly heard at 2:55 in the below video.

This was recorded in August 1952, and was first released to the public in 1975 by Caedmon Records as *J.R.R. Tolkien Reads and Sings His The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers/The Return of the King.*

Additionally, several further examples of "eo" words can be heard in this recording.

- Éomer - 0:03, 0:28, 1:08, 3:16, 7:49
- Théoden - 0:59, 2:46, 3:18, 5:34, 6:12, 7:07, 7:56
- éored - 1:44, 2:53, 3:19, 4:29, 7:54

Comment: This is a good find.

Comment: @Spencer - I lack the linguistic skills to do much more than point to the video and go "it sounds like that". So your answer is also very helpful.